# Permalink of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to get the link to a custom post type - Video. I have achieved this by doing:

```
get_post_type_archive_link( 'video' );
```

This returns http://mylink.co.uk/video which is brillant and exactly what I am looking for. However, when I click onto a custom post type category for example...`LIVE` and it loads the filtered results, the script link using `get_post_type_archive_link( 'video' );` now changes to the `LIVE` category link showing `http://mylink.co.uk/category/live/`.

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
function custom_post_type_video() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Videos', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Video', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Video:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Videos', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No Videos found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Videos found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Video information pages', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'Video', $args );

add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
// Initialize Taxonomy Labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    // Register Custom Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('tagvideo',array('video'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true, // define whether to use a system like tags or categories
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cat-video' ),
    ));

    }


// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_video', 0 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "now points to the LIVE category."? Does the link changed?

Comment: Yeah the link changes to the LIVE category

Comment: So, you mean to say that now `get_post_type_archive_link( 'video' );` is returning this `http://mylink.co.uk/category/live/` on Category pages. Right?

Comment: @OmarTariq that is correct

Comment: can you paste the code of your registering of post type video? I meant to say the code of this function `register_post_type`. Along with arguments. I've a dirty hack available for this question. But I would like to know few things.

Comment: @OmarTariq updated bove

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is it so. I read the code (both yours and WordPress' source code) and didn't find why is it so. I can tell you only two things that might or might not be helpful:-

## First

This line:-

```
register_post_type( 'Video', $args );
```

should be like this:-

```
register_post_type( 'video', $args ); // small v
```

## Second

One quick and dirty workaround that you can do is to 'hard-code' the video post type archive link. Try inserting this code in your functions.php:-

```
function video_post_type_archive_link( $link, $post_type ) {
   if( $post_type === 'video' ) {
      $link = 'http://mylink.co.uk/video' // <-- this should be link to 'video' post type archives
   }
   return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_archive_link', 'video_post_type_archive_link', 10, 2);
```

Now, whenever you'll call this:

```
get_post_type_archive_link( 'video' );
```

You'll get:

```
http://mylink.co.uk/video
```

Only for video custom post type.

Comment: Its really a dirty trick. Make it atleast a little dynamic with `site_url()` and store post_type `video` in a variable.